Conditions for comparing norms of operators that act on the same space
Consider a possibly non-square matrix (or more generally, an operator) $T$.
A neat fact is that:
$$
\| T^* T (T^* T + \mu)^{-1} \| = \| T (T^* T + \mu)^{-1} T^* \|
$$
This quantity is bounded by 1.
The argument proceeds as follows: write $T = U D V^*$, where $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices and $D$ is diagonal. The left-hand side becomes:
$$
\| V D^2 (D^2 + \mu)^{-1} V^* \|
$$
and the right-hand side becomes:
$$
\| U D (D^2 + \mu)^{-1} D U^* \|
$$
Note that this holds even though $T^* T (T^* T + \mu)^{-1} \neq T (T^* T + \mu)^{-1} T^*$; in fact, they act on different spaces.
As an aside, we have:
$$
T^* T (T^* T + \mu)^{-1} = T^* (T T^* + \mu)^{-1} T
$$
Now, I am interested in the following extension of this result: are there conditions under which
$$
\| T^* T (T^* T + S^* S + \mu)^{-1} \| \leq \| T (T^* T + S^* S + \mu)^{-1} T^* \|
$$
There seems to be a sense in which we are trying to commute $T^*$ with $T (T^* T + S^* S + \mu)^{-1}$, which suggests that simultaneous diagonalizability may be part of the solution.
In particular, it seems like the argument goes through if we can express $T^* T = V D V^*$ as before, and now assume:
$$
S^* S = V D' V^*
$$
i.e., $S^* S$ is diagonalized in the eigenbasis of $T^* T$, or vice versa.
Is a sufficient condition for the inequality that $\text{row}(S) = \text{row}(T)$?
Could this be weakened to $\text{row}(T) \subseteq \text{row}(S)$, i.e., $\text{null}(S) \subseteq \text{null}(T)$?

It is worth noting that the reverse inequality,
$$
| T^* T (T^* T + S^* S + \mu)^{-1} | \geq | T (T^* T + S^* S + \mu)^{-1} T^* |,
$$
holds whenever $T$ is an invertible (and hence square) matrix. To see this, note that the matrices under consideration are similar, since
$$
T^{-\star}[T^* T (T^* T + S^* S + \mu)^{-1}]T^\star = T(T^*T + S^S + \mu)^{-1}T^,
$$
that the right-hand side matrix is Hermitian, and that the spectral norm of a Hermitian is equal to its spectral radius (in this case, its largest eigenvalue).

Also, for anyone interested, I give some proofs of that aside over here

I don't think the norm was ever specified or $\mu$ was defined but I am inferring the Spectral norm (Schatten $\infty$ norm) and OP means $\mu I$ for arbitrary $\mu \gt 0$.  Building on @BenGrossmann 's inequality, which holds even for non-square $T$ [check the trace]: If we change to any other Schatten norm we get $| T^* T (T^* T + S^* S + \mu I)^{-1} |{S_p} \geq | T (T^* T + S^* S + \mu I)^{-1} T^* |{S_p}$ for $p\in [1,\infty)$ with equality iff the matrix on the LHS is normal, i.e. Hermitian PD, so yes iff $S^*S$ and $T^*T$ commute.

As usual we can directly show this for Schatten $1$ and $2$ norms but other choices of $p$ are going to require something like majorization theory (beyond the scope).  Assuming "$\text{row}(S)$' refers to the rowspace of $S$, then OP's conjecture at the end seems to imply  that all $n\times n$ Hermitian PD matrices commute which of course is not true.
